# Page title returns me array of data instead of a specific data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am not able to show the name of the Hunter through the relationship between tables, it is returning the array of results.

This returns me

```
View reward of <?php echo e({"id":4, "name_hunter":"Gon Freecss"...})
```

I want to

```
View reward of Gon Freecss
```

##### `HunterController.php`

```
public function show($id)
{
    $rewarded = RewardedModel::find($id);
    $hunter = HunterModel::select('_id', 'name_hunter')->get();
    $reward = RewardModel::select('_id', 'description_reward')->get();
    return view('rewarded.view', compact(['rewarded', 'reward', 'hunter']));
}
```

##### `view.php`

```html
@section('title', "View reward of {{ $rewarded->hunter->name_hunter }}")
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: change it to `@section('title', "View reward of " . $hunter->first()->name_hunter )`

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want a single result, use `->first()`, not `->get()`.

So, `$hunter = HunterModel::select('_id', 'name_hunter')->get();` should be `$hunter = HunterModel::select('_id', 'name_hunter')->first();`, same for any other data.

`->get` returns a Collection of data (even if it found or got a single result), `->first` will return an object (a model, but an `Std` in your case), so that will fix it.

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $rewarded = RewardedModel::find($id);
    $hunter = HunterModel::select('_id', 'name_hunter')->first();
    $reward = RewardModel::select('_id', 'description_reward')->first();

    return view('rewarded.view', compact(['rewarded', 'reward', 'hunter']));
}
```

Read the documentation about [`->first`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) and [`->get`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#building-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I think your usage of `compact()` is incorrect.

Instead of:

```
return view('rewarded.view', compact(['rewarded', 'reward', 'hunter']));
```

Try this:

```
return view('rewarded.view', compact('rewarded', 'reward', 'hunter'));
```

Comment: You may think so, but both forms are correct (and identical in what they do), see https://php.net/compact . Just FYI.